# emacs org mode: (conditional) if cell is empty then

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-table

How do you express the following conditional for an org mode table?

```
for every cell between the 2nd and 3rd hline: 
  if the cell is empty, 
    set the contents of the cell to todays date.
  else
    leave the cells contents as they are.
```

so, given the following table, i would like to insert todays date in the empty cell.

```
|------------------|
| date             |
|------------------|
| [2014-05-23 Fri] |
| [2014-05-24 Sat] |
|                  |
|------------------|
```

Comment: What is the whitsepace in the middle, please -- tab(s) or spaces?

Comment: Not sure. Whatever org puts in empty cells when they are created.

Comment: If there are two empty cells at the bottom, do you want to put today's date in both or just the first?

Comment: Both. I would like to put todays date into any empty cell between 2 given hline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The custom calc function appendToday will do what you want. It handles the case where all fields between the hlines are empty as well.

```
(defmath appendToday (idx v)
  (let ((d (date (month (now)) (day (now))))
        (len (vlen v)))
    (if (<= idx len)
      (if (equal (cadr v) 0)
        d
        (nth idx v)
      )
      d
    )
  )
)
```

The table before evaluation looks like:

```
|------------------|
| <2014-05-26 Mon> |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|------------------|
#+TBLFM: @I..@II$1=appendToday(@#,@I..@II$1)
```

The table after evaluation looks like:

```
|------------------|
| <2014-05-26 Mon> |
| <2014-05-28 Wed> |
| <2014-05-28 Wed> |
| <2014-05-28 Wed> |
| <2014-05-28 Wed> |
| <2014-05-28 Wed> |
|------------------|
#+TBLFM: @I..@II$1=appendToday(@#,@I..@II$1)
```